# gettype and unknown type in php

Tags: php

I've just started to practice with PHP built-in `gettype()` and its return value. This function is capable to return testing result such as `boolean`, `integer`, `unknown type`, etc. But among those testing result, there's one caught my eyes: **unknown type**.

After reading [`gettype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) and trying to find some reference here, i can not get any.

So, the question is what kind of type can be categorized as `unknown type`? 
Is it possible or am I just missing reading something?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is one unknown type for you:

```
$f = fopen('somefile.txt','r');
echo gettype($f); // resource
fclose($f); 
echo gettype($f); // unknown
```

Basically, whenever a [resource pointer](http://de.php.net/manual/en/resource.php) is closed, the variable holding the handle will point to an *unknown* resource. Another example would be with GD'S imagecreate/imagedestroy.

**Note:** as of PHP 7.2, this no longer holds true. `gettype` will return `resource (closed)` then.

Comment: Wow, PHP. Outputting the "closed" file resource still shows "Resource id #x" but it's type is suddenly unkown. +1 Nice answer, though

Comment: Another fun fact. gettype returns "object" for closures due to the way it was implemented.

Comment: this answer is not true anymore for PHP 7.2 `echo gettype($f); return resource (closed)`

Comment: @yuklia well, 7.2 is not released yet, but yes, it will resource (closed) as of 7.2. I'll add a note to the answer.

Answer (score 10):

According to the PHP source code it's the "default" case in the switch statement for that function. My guess is that is is there way of handling an internal error.

Comment: PHP just got a bit more messy in my eyes.

Comment: +1 for checking with the sourcecode. The downvote is totally undeserved in my opinion.