# Can't get php to display directory and fgets?

Tags: php, directory, filenames, fgets

I'm just trying something where I display all the files in a directory and then I display some info next to them with fgets. I can't seem to get this to work. I kinda suck at php at the moment but I basically want it to display a tr with two td's per tr. One td with the filename, the other td with the "description" which will just be some info I put in the first part of the file.

```
<table>
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('desktop/')) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {

      $string = "$file";     


$searchArray = array("_", ".php");
$replaceArray = array("", "");
$string = str_replace($searchArray,$replaceArray,$string);
$handle = @fopen("desktop/$file", "r");
if ($handle) {
while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
    echo $buffer;
}
if (!feof($handle)) {
    echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
}
fclose($handle);
}
echo "<tr><td><a href=desktop/$file>$string\n</a></td><td>$buffer</td></tr>"; 
    }
}
closedir($handle);
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the issue? What permissions are your directory? Are you protected against file-traversal attacks?

Comment: Warning: readdir(): 5 is not a valid Directory resource in C:\wamp\www\tech\pc.php on line 16

Warning: closedir(): 5 is not a valid Directory resource in C:\wamp\www\tech\pc.php on line 38

Comment: To confirm, does `var_dump($handle)` show `bool(false)`?

Comment: You might wanna wrap the value of the **href** attr. within quotes, as a start: `<a href=\"desktop/$file\">`

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2488923/344643) seems to imply that the resource has been closed, but I can't say why that has happened...

Answer (score 0):

You redefine "$handle" which casues your problem.

$handle is initially the variable holding the "directory" resource. You then re-use it to hold the file resource. Then when you return back the the directory resource to get the name of the next file, $handle is no longer the directory resource, but a file - so problems arise.

Call the first one "$dirHandle" and the second "$fileHandle" as this will make it clearer for you?

---

Edit: how to only get the first line (as requested in comments):

```
if ($handle) { 
    if (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) { 
        echo "<tr><td><a href=desktop/$file>$string\n</a></td><td>$buffer</td></tr>";  
    }
}
```

(Note: you probably also want to use htmlspecialchars() to make it a bit safe too)

Comment: That's what I thought, I tried it earlier and something went wrong, but I'll try again :P

Comment: fgets gets one line at a time. Your code says "get one line, and if it's not the last, get me next, and if that's not the last, get me the next etc". So change your "while" to an "if" surronding the fgets. See edit in answer.

Comment: Quickest way: if (is_file($file)). The PHP manual's really good for things like that ;). Otherwise I'll take you down the DirectoryIterator and object route, which actually gives you more control... http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php (check the first comments for an example, but don't copy verbatim and use "unlink" and that actually means "delete"!)